# Empty response data for fetch call

Tags: react-native, promise, fetch

react native fetch call (es5) returning undefined response. Here is the code of my fetch call.

```
 body = {"username":"Gdgf","password":"dfgdfgdfg","remember":""}
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fetch(`${FINAL_URL}users/login_app?app=1&submit=1`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    // 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    // 'content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(responseData => console.log('responseData', responseData)) // console output is --> responseData []
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
```

attaching the screnshot of postman too, to show that api is working.

[image: POSTman for the same API call]

Comment: Can you show this in console log please? `${FINAL_URL}users/login_app?app=1&submit=1` Is it showing the correct path?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it

Comment: Reza, www is missing. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Your welcome. I put an official answer for this question. If your problem is fixed please mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please delete this part "var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { " and check if it is working with a simple fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this problem occurs when you don't call your end point correctly. As you said in the comments, in the console log of `${FINAL_URL}users/login_app?app=1&submit=1` you missed the www, which makes the response undefined.  If you still have a problem please delete `new Promise`  section from the fetch.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try changing the following line:

```
then(responseData => console.log('responseData', responseData))
```

to

```
then(responseData => console.log('responseData', JSON.stringify(responseData)))
```

What is the console output now?

Comment: Still the same, responseData []

Comment: is the device in the same network as the device where you tested using postman?